# Hidden pro-accessibility information impact on SEO

Tags: html, css, seo, hide, hidden

Im making some kind of online board game. And of course this will not work without JavaScript so I want to put an information about it for users which have disabled JavaScript. There is my example code:

```
.no-js #content-container:before {
    content: "Sorry! This site will not work without JavaScript.";
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 9999999;
    //of course there goes more styles for fonts etc. 
}
```

I believe this is good solution for SEO reasons.

But how Google behave if I put this into, let's say, `<p>` tag and hide it with `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`? Is that bad for SEO?

Just to be clean - I know this is really a few words and this one particular case will not make big impact on SEO, but I'm asking in a wider sense - if we have more hidden informations on our page.

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Isn't Google "think" it's cloaking?

Comment: No. Cloaking implies you're doing it for malicious purposes, your purpose is anything but.